# Integration of an Flex/PHP web application with a Drupal site?

Tags: drupal

We are planning our new business application in Flex/PHP/Zend/MySQL. We also have our company website with some static pages currently. What we want to achieve is to convert the static site into a Drupal site and integrate our business application into the drupal site.

Basically, we want to have a single user authentication/authorization across the drupal site and the business application, in other words, we want to utilize Drupal's user management in our business application. Also, the entry point to the business app will be one of the pages within the drupal site.

As I am new to Drupal and we are still evaluating the technology, it would be greatly appreciated if some brief steps could be provided on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

What we do is write a custom module that renders either json or xml that is consumed by the flex apps.  Basically you learn how to implement hook menu in a drupal module...  Not much drupal code require.   Find me on drupal.org contact form and id be happy to send sample code.  Metzlerd is my drupal name.

It woul also be good to become familiar with dbtng, drupal's database api.

Comment: Thanks, Dave. I've registered on Drupal.org and sent you an email.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying is exactly I am doing right now.

You have to use drupal as a back end for your flex app and since drupal is php/mysql it is just the same as a php application interfacing with flex app.

Apart from Drupal User management you can even utilize drupal's modules & content management power. You can create custom drupal module and even expose them to flex.

You will be needing Services and AmfPHP modules to enable in your drupal site.  Services Module will expose your drupal services (Conetent read write,edit, User etc. etc.) to your Flex App.

And Amfphp will be handling your flex app data communication in AMF format directly so don't need to worry about much XML. You can just go around and create a flex app just as you create a flex php app.

Hope this helps.